# How to set app icon for linux revisited and how does xfreerdp do it

Tags: c++, linux, svg, icons, appimage

I discovered that my appimag-ed application does not show any app icon in the window manager when launched, even though it has the icon inside itself. By the way, e.g., Obsidian app does suffer from this problem. In general, from searching on the Web, it looks like appimage fails with icons. Here e.g., a person also answers that appimage fails to provide app icons for a window manager: [Electron Linux: .AppImage is not showing the icon, while .deb is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543680/electron-linux-appimage-is-not-showing-the-icon-while-deb-is). And also, when I load any app from https://appimage.github.io/apps/ -- at least on Fedora 33 and 35 -- I can see no app icons when launching them.

I tried to use workarounds like `QMainWindow::setWindowIcon()` or setting env variable `XDG_DATA_DIRS`, but it did not help -- these approaches can be found on appimage-related sites.

I discovered answers on SO like by these links:

- [Qt Creator - how to set application icon for ubuntu linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328383/qt-creator-how-to-set-application-icon-for-ubuntu-linux?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How do I give a C++ program an icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946945/how-do-i-give-a-c-program-an-icon)

The idea of the answers is that you could not do such a thing and you have to install your `.desktop` file and icons to `/usr/share` via deb/rpm/etc. packages.

However, I discovered that it looks like xfreerdp carries its icon with it: I tried to change my system paths to icons (`/usr/share/icons` to `/usr/share/icons_`) temporarily and the xfreerdp's icon was still there in the window manager, while those of other apps grayed out. Also, I searched for .svg or .png icons of xfreerdp on the whole os and have not found anything.

So I an just curious how they can do it? I looked into its source code on Github, but could not understand. It's just an enigma for me really. Maybe, anybody has an idea how they do it or how this can be achieved at all?

Comment: You can embeds icon bitmap in your source code, for example as a const array of integers, then loads it and set it as window icon directly using LibX11 or XCB... I have some code to do that using XCB. I don't know if such method will be suitable for your purpose.

Comment: Well, why can't the image be stored just as a file and loaded then? Xfreerdp is okay with its icon on Wayland too. So I am not sure if this is the method you are talking about. Perhaps, the solution is interesting anyway. I personally have a qt app. Sorry, if my answer is confusing.

Comment: QT, GTK or other, this does not matter since using Xlib or XCB you are talking directly with the display manager, you bypass the window/desktop manager. I don't know if this is the method used by Xfreerdp, but, if such thing is possible for X11 via XCB, I guess this is also possible in Wayland environment, but I don't know Wayland. Also, yes, you can use this method with an externally loaded bitmap data from file.

Comment: @Sedenion, I see. Could you, please, post the method? I think it's interesting regardless of xfreerdp. I will upvote it definitely.

Comment: While writing answer and digging my old code, I figured out that to use this method, you'ill need to get the proper X window identifier/handle from your QT Window object, and this would lead you to a whole new problem... I have no idea how to do this. I see QX11Info allow to get X connection, but it is very unclear how to get window handle... I can give you the code, but this will only move the problem further.

Comment: I see. Well, anyway, I think this may be useful for me or for other people, though I don't insist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an incomplete answer, since it only cover the X11 case and does not describe how to translate from QT object to X11 handles. **I don't even know if this method will solve your specific problem**.

The idea is to talk directly with X server to set the window icon, here, using the XCB API (same thing can be achieved using Xlib).

The X server need the bitmap data to be provided as 32 bit **ARGB** format, with two 32 bit unsigned integers ahead for image width and height. In a visual way, this what X server wait for:

```
 4 bytes   4 bytes   4 bytes   4 bytes   4 bytes
[ WIDTH  ][ HEIGHT ][  ARGB  ][  ARGB  ][  ARGB  ]...
```

Indeed, if you load image from common encoded image format like PNG, JPEG or other, you'll need to properly decode image data to RGB(A), then convert bitmap to the proper ARGB format...

Here is the function to set the icon of any X windows. The first parameter `c` is the handle to the X server connection, the second `w` the handle/identifier (actually it is a simple integer) to X window. The third parameter `icon_data` is the icon data buffer as described above and the last parameter `icon_size` is the size, in bytes, of the buffer pointed by `icon_data`.

```
setWindowIcon(xcb_connection_t* c, xcb_window_t w, uint32_t* icon_data, size_t icon_size)
{
  // get the _NET_WM_ICON atom
  xcb_intern_atom_reply_t* r;
  r = xcb_intern_atom_reply(c, xcb_intern_atom(c,1,12,"_NET_WM_ICON"), 0);
  xcb_atom_t _NET_WM_ICON = r->atom;
  free(r);

  // get the CARDINAL atom
  r = xcb_intern_atom_reply(c, xcb_intern_atom(c,1,8,"CARDINAL"), 0);
  xcb_atom_t CARDINAL = r->atom;
  free(r);

  // change window property
  xcb_change_property(c, XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE, w, _NET_WM_ICON, CARDINAL, 32, icon_size, icon_data);

  // make sure everything is done
  free(xcb_get_input_focus_reply(c, xcb_get_input_focus(c), NULL));
}
```

As you can see, the main purpose of this code is to modify/set a specific window property identified by `_NET_WM_ICON`. You'll find some information about this X specific protocol and syntax here :

- https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html
- https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/properties-and-atoms.html

Notice that, I am not personally a great expert of X server protocols, I only digged some time ago this specific section for some low-level window management purpose.

Comment: I have just discovered a funny thing: there is wlfreerdp for wayland. So xfreerdp is like for X11, afaiu. So maybe, they are using xcb or smth like that indeed.